# applescript to open google search query in youtube

Tags: applescript

I am using the code below to open youtube with google query in applescript as the new google does not carry my search string to youtube.Unable to open url in firefix with the google search string in firefox. I really appreciate any help.Thanks in advance.

I am getting an error here :

```
tell application "Firefox" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "l" using command down
    keystroke "c" using command down

    set tr to get the clipboard


end tell



return trimgoogle(tr)
on trimgoogle(sourceAddress)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"#"}
    set addressParts to (every text item in sourceAddress) as list
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    set nameOnly to item 2 of addressParts

    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"&"}
    set addressParts2 to (every text item in nameOnly) as list
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    set nameOnly1 to item 1 of addressParts2
    set nameOnly2 to nameOnly1


    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"="}
    set addressParts21 to (every text item in nameOnly2) as list
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    set nameOnly12 to item 2 of addressParts21


    set newurl to "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" & nameOnly12

    return newurl

end trimgoogle

tell application "Firefox"
OpenURL  newurl
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
tell application "Firefox"
    open location newurl
end tell
```

EDIT:

Firefox does not activate itself automatically, so I just tried this:

```
tell application "Firefox"
    activate
    open location "http://www.wikipedia.com/"
end tell
```

which works here.

Here more about encoding text:
http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/sbrt/sbrt-08.html

EDIT2:
OK, I see what you mean, that would be solved like this:

```
tell application "Firefox" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "l" using command down
    keystroke "c" using command down
    set tr to get the clipboard
end tell

set newurl to my trimgoogle(tr)

tell application "Firefox"
    activate
    open location newurl
end tell

on trimgoogle(sourceAddress)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"#"}
    set addressParts to (every text item in sourceAddress) as list
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    set nameOnly to item 2 of addressParts

    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"&"}
    set addressParts2 to (every text item in nameOnly) as list
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    set nameOnly1 to item 1 of addressParts2
    set nameOnly2 to nameOnly1

    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {"="}
    set addressParts21 to (every text item in nameOnly2) as list
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
    set nameOnly12 to item 2 of addressParts21

    set newurl to "http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" & nameOnly12

    return newurl

end trimgoogle
```

Comment: I tried that also but it does nothing !! There is no error in the code .But new window(tab does not open).

Comment: Try it with a hardcoded url. If it works you must encode your url (in this case, the contents of "nameOnly12") - I just tried it again here on OS 10.8.2 with latest Firefox and it opens a valid location

Comment: made newurl global and it started working .can you tell me any other way to do it without making newurl global??

Comment: Just to clarify: Firefox does not have a command called "OpenURL" but "open location http://..." seems to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot it was a great help :)